# Jsp : How to pass dynamic variable using a hyperlink

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to pass a (dynamic) variable through a hyperlink.

```
sname = "my image location";

out.println("hyperlink targeted_url name = sname ");
```

on targeted_url :

```
myvalue = request.getParameter("name").toString();
```

But whenever I tried to output that location, the output show me **sname**.

Is there any solution? I don't want to use session, cookie or form.

Is it possible within hyperlink?

Comment: What about using a parameter in the get request so something like `/to/somewhere?name=myValue`

Comment: show code where your create your anchor

Comment: Try this, **out.println("hyperlink targeted_url name = "+sname);**

Comment: @javaL I don't understand from where the data is passed, If OP needs to send data with hyperlink why can't OP use query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not evaluating sname in your println. This will do that:

```
out.println("hyperlink targeted_url name = " + sname);
```

You haven't shown where you are creating your link, but when doing that you need to do the same thing - append the sname variable instead of including it as a string literal.

Comment: I have tried this. 
out.println("<a href='/none/urlreceive.jsp?name="+sname+"'>See Whats inside your mind.</a>");

But it showed me blank page and in the url it looks like

http://localhost:8080/none/urlreceive.jsp?name=%3Cimg%20border=

Comment: It looks like your "my image location" is set to an entire <img> tag instead of just its location - hence you are getting the escaped version of beginning of that tag `<img border =`... in your url and it cuts off at the first quotation mark in the <img> tag. You need your sname variable to contain only the name you want, not the img tag.